# Multiple documents, multiple table of contents, in one file

Tags: table-of-contents

To simplify the management of multiple books, I put all of them together into them together into one file, then used `\cleardoublepage`, `\setcounter{page}{1}` and a new `titlepage` environment to specify the beginning of the second document.

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        This is the first title page.
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{This chapter should appear in the first title page}

    \cleardoublepage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \begin{titlepage}
        This is the second title page.
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{This chapter should appear in the first second page}
    \chapter{This chapter should also appear in the first second page}
\end{document}
```

However, the first `tableofcontents` loads displays all chapters and the second `tableofcontents` shows no chapters.

- Is `\cleardoublepage` and `\setcounter{page}{1}` the proper way to reset the document?
- How can I have more than one table of contents within the same file?

Comment: LaTeX way of creating a table of contents is to write a line for each TOC entry into a file named `\jobname.toc`. (I.e. every time a `\section` or so is encountered.)  The `\tableofcontents` macro basically (via the `\@starttoc` macro) reads in that file and clears it afterwards. Therefore, you can't "abuse" the `\tableofcontents` for your purpose.

Comment: It might be a better solution to have them in different files and then join only the *pdf*s with the iad of the `pdfpages` package.
PS. It's a pity that you deleted your question about "omitting" once-used counters: this is something many people might find useful, I was just about to start coding that;).

Comment: The `titletoc` package, for example, would let you have multiple independent ToCs, but simply resetting the page counter will produce problems with `hyperref` (the typical `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.4}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored` warnings). It's better to work on different `.tex` files and possibly use `xr` or to use `memoir` (as suggested in another of your questions).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that question was not a good question because I found `inparaenum` does what I needed. Now, I see maybe others need that too. I have reposted the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `titletoc` package provides the tools that you want using `\startlist{toc}` and `\printlist{toc}`.

See Section 7.4 of the documentation for more details- a complete MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
        This is the first title page.
\end{titlepage}

\startlist{toc}
\printlist{toc}{}{\section*{My first toc}}
\chapter{This chapter should appear in the first title page}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{titlepage}
       This is the second title page.
\end{titlepage}

\startlist{toc}
\printlist{toc}{}{\section*{My second toc}}

\chapter{This chapter should appear in the first second page}
\chapter{This chapter should also appear in the first second page}

\end{document}
```