# two different lists of figure in the same document

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my Phd thesis with parts chapters and sections. It is divided in two very different subjects of research and I'd like to have a clear separation in the document and in the Table of Contents. In particular I'd like to have two different List of Figure and two List of Tables at the end of each parts of the document and not all together at the end of the document. I think that I have to create some new environment but I'm not able to get my result.

To construct two different new figure environments I simply inserted:

```
\newenvironment{myfigure1}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}
```

in all chapters of the first Part of the document and

```
\newenvironment{myfigure2}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}
```

in all chapters of the second Part

Also I modified the main file as follows:

```
\newlistof{myfigure1}{List of Figure}
```

after the chapters of the first Part  and

```
\newlistof{myfigure2}{List of Figure}
```

after the chapters of the second Part in the main file.

Sorry for my naivety

Comment: Is this helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38562/14757

Comment: Please add details on what you have tried and what about it is not working.

Comment: @Sigur,  your example makes two toc ?, but I'd like one toc and two lists of figure and two list of tables one for each parts.

Comment: Are you using the `memoir` document class?

Comment: No I'm using book class

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to do such things if you use the titletoc package (included in titlesec): it defines the commands

```
\startlist{lof}
\stoplist{lof}
\resumelist{lof}
\printlist{lof}
```

and similarly for lot. They have a name as an optional argument. See details in § 6.3 of the doc.